# get array elements individually from user entered values

Tags: java, arrays

So with my loop code below

```
System.out.print("How many values? ");
numOfValues = input.nextInt();

int[] values = new int[numOfValues]; 
for(int i=0; i<numOfValues;i++)
{
    System.out.print("Value " + (i+1) + " :");
    values[i] = input.nextInt();
}
```

I need to see what the user entered into each element of values array individually so taht I can print them out to screen. Is this possible? I am passing in `numOfValues` as the arrays index so I can't tell how many elements will be in the array itself.

for ex: the screen will show: You entered: 2,5,3,5,4

But how do I print out the exact number of elements in the array? Since I am not giving it a fixed number like `values[3];`.

Comment: Your question is not clear...what `numOfValues` contain, not exact number of elements?

Comment: The array will have `numOfValues` elements.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays have the length field, so you can just call `values.length` which will return the size (`numOfValues`) of the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user not having to specify the size of the array from the beginning you can use an ArrayList. You can insert items on the fly and it will grow automatically.

```
ArrayList<Integer> elements = new ArrayList<Integer>();

elements.add(x);
```

You can then tell the number of elements the user inserted by `elements.size()`